# How to prevent stack wind-up operator overloads

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting stack overflow in this apparently benign code:

```
    public static bool operator == (AccessLevel al1, AccessLevel al2)
    {
        if (al1 == null && al2 == null)
            return true;

        if (al1 == null || al2 == null)
            return false;

        if (al1._Value == al2._Value)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public static bool operator != (AccessLevel al1, AccessLevel al2)
    {
        if (al1 == null && al2 == null)
            return false;

        if (al1 == null || al2 == null)
            return true;

        if (al1._Value != al2._Value)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

What appears to be happening is that in the test for null in operator overload, the == overload is called again, and again, and again until the stack wind up.
Possible solutions here is to use the "Equals" override, which would look like Equals(null) returning true... but how to code that without using the == overload ? Is this the correct implementation:

```
        public override bool Equals(object o)
        {
            if (o == null)
                return true;
            if ((AccessLevel)o == this)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Or could one say something like this:

```
        public static bool operator == (AccessLevel al1, AccessLevel al2)
        {
            if (al1 is null && al2 is null)
                return true;

            if (al1 is null || al2 is null)
                return false;

            if (al1._Value == al2._Value)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Any insight on how to correctly handle this?

Comment: Try `is null` instead of `== null`.

Comment: The opertor `is` is for testing type purpose only meaning it checks if the result of an expression is of a given type. `null` is not a type (class or structure) but a "value". Other than that you ended up with a `StackOverflowException` because you are using the operator `==` that you are currently overriding.

Comment: @RivoR. The _is operator_ has been a part of pattern matching since C# 7 and the `is null` pattern [guarantees that no user overloads will be called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is#:~:text=When%20you%20match%20an%20expression%20against%20null%2C%20the%20compiler%20guarantees%20that%20no%20user%2Doverloaded%20%3D%3D%20or%20!%3D%20operator%20is%20invoked.).

Answer (score 2):

To implement equality tests "properly", use:

```
public class AccessLevel : IEquatable<AccessLevel>
{
    ...
    
    public override int GetHashCode() => _Value.GetHashCode();
    
    public override bool Equals(object obj) 
        => obj is AccessLevel other 
        && Equals(other);
    
    public bool Equals(AccessLevel other)
    {
        if (other is null) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return _Value == other._Value;
    }
    
    public static bool operator ==(AccessLevel left, AccessLevel right)
        => Equals(left, right);
    
    public static bool operator !=(AccessLevel left, AccessLevel right)
        => !Equals(left, right);
}
```

Comment: Right! Thanks for that!

Comment: However, the class is defined as public class AccessLevel : EMSDevices.BasicDescriptionLookup<AccessLevels> so I'd need to have multiple inheritance, which as we know c# doesn't support.....I would need to create an interface class as well?

Comment: You don't need multiple inheritance; you're only inheriting from one class. You're just implementing an interface, and there is no restriction to the number of interfaces a class can implement.

Comment: Turns out there was no hardship in inheriting the base class from IEquatable, viz:  public class BasicDescriptionLookup<EnumDef> : IEquatable<EnumDef> so derived classes could properly override Equals method.

Comment: Being pedantic here: you **implement** an interface; you don't *inherit from* it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option would be semantically incorrect, as well as inefficient. `Equals(null)` should never return true. As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0#system-object-equals(system-object)):

> The following statements must be true for all implementations of the `Equals(Object)` method. [...]
>
> ...
>
> - `x.Equals(null)` returns `false`.

Your second approach of using `is` is correct and more idiomatic in modern C#, although I'd argue the final part would be clearer as just:

```cs
return al1._Value == al2._Value;
```

Your `Equals` method can then just be implemented as:

```cs
public override bool Equals(object o) => this == o as AccessLevel;
```

(It's up to you whether the semantics are implemented in the `==` operator or in the `Equals` method, but it's best to implement them in just one of the two places to avoid duplication and potential inconsistency.)